# Arquillian Unable to deploy

Tags: jboss-arquillian

I am using Arquillian in my application, but any test can't deploy, for all test I have the same error:

*org.jboss.arquillian.persistence.core.exception.DataSourceNotFoundException: Unable to find data source for given name: java:/analyticsTestDS*

I have in standalone.xml datasource, xa-datasource and driver configuration. This configuration is working in other project that use the same server to connect in database.

**This is the Junit log:**

```
    org.jboss.arquillian.persistence.core.exception.DataSourceNotFoundException: Unable to find data source for given name: java:/analyticsTestDS
    at org.jboss.arquillian.persistence.core.datasource.JndiDataSourceProvider.lookupDataSource(JndiDataSourceProvider.java:62)
 ...
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException; remaining name 'java:/analyticsTestDS'
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.local.localContextRoot.lookup(localContextRoot.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.local.localContextRoot.lookup(localContextRoot.java:536)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.persistence.core.datasource.JndiDataSourceProvider.lookupDataSource(JndiDataSourceProvider.java:58)
    ... 86 more
```

**And this is the Jboss log:**

```
...
    [0m[0m11:50:43,832 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.validation.AbstractValidatorContextResolver] (MSC service thread 1-7) Unable to find CDI supporting ValidatorFactory. Using default ValidatorFactory
    [0m[0m11:50:43,973 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS017534: Registered web context: /test
    [0m[0m11:50:44,117 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "test.war" (runtime-name : "test.war")
    [0m[0m11:50:46,039 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS017535: Unregistered web context: /test
    [0m[0m11:50:46,074 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) JBAS011410: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'test.war#analytics-datasource'
    [0m[0m11:50:46,079 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Infinium' 6.0.2.Final
    [0m[0m11:50:46,322 INFO  [org.infinispan.jmx.CacheJmxRegistration] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) ISPN000031: MBeans were successfully registered to the platform MBean server.
    [0m[0m11:50:46,325 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) JBAS010281: Started local-query cache from hibernate container
    [0m[0m11:50:46,331 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS016009: Stopping weld service for deployment test.war
    [0m[0m11:50:46,354 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) JBAS011410: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'test.war#analytics-datasource'
    [0m[0m11:50:46,365 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010282: Stopped local-query cache from hibernate container
    [0m[0m11:50:46,476 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment test.war (runtime-name: test.war) in 447ms
    [0m[0m11:50:46,617 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS014901: Content removed from location /usr/local/jboss/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/standalone/data/content/31/e043268729c5760564bfb64faec9b14c158cee/content
    [0m[0m11:50:46,617 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS018558: Undeployed "test.war" (runtime-name: "test.war")
    [0m[0m11:50:46,639 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS010409: Unbound data source [java:/analyticsDS]
    [0m[0m11:50:46,639 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010409: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
    [0m[0m11:50:46,640 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010409: Unbound data source [java:/analyticsAuthDS]
    [0m[0m11:50:46,642 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010409: Unbound data source [java:/analyticsTestDS]
    [0m[0m11:50:46,642 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS017532: Host default-host stopping
    [0m[0m11:50:46,645 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010409: Unbound data source [java:/analyticsTimerDS]
    [0m[0m11:50:46,650 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010418: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = h2
    [0m[0m11:50:46,652 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010418: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = postgresnoxa
    [0m[0m11:50:46,652 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS017521: Undertow HTTP listener default suspending
    [0m[33m11:50:46,652 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) IJ000615: Destroying active connection in pool: analyticsTestDS (org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection@1c90a7bb)
    [0m[33m11:50:46,653 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) IJ000615: Destroying active connection in pool: analyticsTestDS (org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection@12575a59)
    [0m[33m11:50:46,653 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) IJ000615: Destroying active connection in pool: analyticsTestDS (org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection@1668cccb)
    [0m[0m11:50:46,653 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS017520: Undertow HTTP listener default stopped, was bound to /127.0.0.1:8080
    [0m[0m11:50:46,663 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS017506: Undertow 1.1.8.Final stopping
    [0m[0m11:50:46,668 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010418: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = postgresql
    [0m[0m11:50:46,683 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015950: WildFly 8.2.1.Final "Tweek" stopped in 44ms
    [0m
```

**And the test:**

```
package com.atomsail.analytics.datasource.service;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

import java.io.File;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedHashMap;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.InSequence;
import org.jboss.arquillian.persistence.DataSource;
import org.jboss.arquillian.persistence.UsingDataSet;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.Archive;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.maven.Maven;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.maven.PomEquippedResolveStage;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import com.atomsail.analytics.datasource.dao.data.DatasourceDataDAOLocal;
import com.atomsail.analytics.entities.datasourcedata.DatasourceData;
import com.atomsail.analytics.test.jdbc.PostgresDBTestCase;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
@DataSource("java:/analyticsTestDS")
@UsingDataSet("datasets/remove-data-dao.xml")
public class RemoveDataServiceImplTest extends PostgresDBTestCase {

    @Deployment
    public static Archive<?> createTestArchive() {

            PomEquippedResolveStage pom = Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml");
            File[] commonsLang = pom.resolve(       "org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core", 
                                             "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator",                                                   
                                             "org.apache.tika:tika-parsers",
                                             "pentaho-kettle:kettle-core",
                                             "pentaho-kettle:kettle-engine",
                                             "pentaho:pentaho-metadata",                                                            
                                             "org.scannotation:scannotation",
                                             "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3",
                                             "monetdb:monetdb-jdbc",
                                             "pentaho:metastore",
                                             "simple-jndi:simple-jndi",
                                             "joda-time:joda-time").withTransitivity().asFile();

            System.out.println(commonsLang.toString()); 

            WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
                                       .addPackages(true, "com.atomsail.analytics.datasource")
                                       .addAsResource("META-INF/test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
                                       .addAsWebInfResource("ejb/remove-data-jboss-ejb3.xml", "jboss-ejb3.xml")
                                       .addAsWebInfResource("test-web.xml", "web.xml")
                                       .addAsResource("truncate_all_app.sql")
                                       .addAsLibraries(commonsLang);

            System.out.println(war.toString(true));         
        return war;
    }

    private String baseURL = getBaseURL();

    @EJB
    private DatasourceDataDAOLocal datasourceDataDao;

    @Test
    @InSequence(1)
    public void removeData() {

        assertNotNull(datasourceDataDao);

        // more code here

    }

    @Override
    protected String dropDDLScript() {
        return "truncate_all_app.sql";
    }

}
```

**My arquillian.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

    <defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0" />
    <container qualifier="jboss" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <property name="jbossHome">/usr/local/jboss/wildfly-8.2.1.Final</property>
            <property name="javaVmArguments">-Xms512m -Xmx3048m</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>

</arquillian>
```

Comment: What's in your arquillian.xml file? You're probably not using your standalone.xml file for the server startup. You can tell wildfly to use the correct file, or you can use a -ds.xml file in your deployment war.

Comment: @LightGuard I already tried use -ds.xml, but i get the same error
Put in the test deploy
 **.addAsWebInfResource("wildfly-ds.xml")**

Answer (score 0):

In your arquillian.xml you can add the configuration it tell wildfly which xml config to use:

```
<container qualifier="jboss" default="true">
    <configuration>
        <property name="jbossHome">${jboss.home}</property>
        <property name="serverConfig">standalone-full.xml</property>
        <!-- uncomment below for debugging
        <property name="javaVmArguments">-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8787</property>
        -->
    </configuration>
</container>
```

Obviously if you're using something different not in the main deploy of wildfly then change the path to the file, but that should tell wildfly which version to use if you already have your datasources setup there.